# Memcpy function optimzation

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, memory-optimization

Here is my memcpy algorithm I've been working on:

```
static void* memcpy(void* destination, const void* source, size_t size) {
        char* dest = (char*)destination;
        const char* src = (const char*)source;

        //check if length is greater than 16 bytes
        if ((size - 16) < 33) {
            while (size > 15) {
                //wtf even is this, assembly in c++? am i a assembly developer too now?
                auto val = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(src));
                _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)dest, val);
                dest += 16;
                src += 16;
                size -= 16;
            }
        }
#ifdef __AVX512__
        else if((size - 32) < 65){
            while (size > 31) {
                //wtf even is this, assembly in c++? am i a assembly developer too now?
                auto val = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)(src));
                _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)dest, val);
                dest += 32;
                src += 32;
                size -= 32;
            }
        }
        else if(size > 65 ) {
            while (size > 31) {
                //wtf even is this, assembly in c++? am i a assembly developer too now?
                auto val = _mm512_loadu_si512((__m512i*)(src));
                _mm512_storeu_si512((__m512i*)dest, val);
                dest += 32;
                src += 32;
                size -= 32;
            }
        }
#else
        else if (size > 32) {
            while (size > 31) {
                //wtf even is this, assembly in c++? am i a assembly developer too now?
                auto val = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)(src));
                _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)dest, val);
                dest += 32;
                src += 32;
                size -= 32;
            }
        }

#endif

        while (size--) {
            *dest++ = *src++;
        }

        /*if (length > 16) {
            src += length - 16;
            dest += length - 16;
            auto val = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(src));
            _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)(dest), val);
        }
        else {
            for (; index < length; ++index) {
                *dest++ = *src++;
            }
        }*/

        return destination;
    }
```

I don't think my cpu supports AVX 512 so I disabled it for now. I'm trying to get this algorithm as close to std::memcpy as I can, but I'm not there just yet. Any ideas on how I can make this faster?

Here are the times I tested with 999,999 iterations and averaged the result:

```
Copying 1361 bytes:

Mine ms: 0.000233
C++ STL ms: 0.000230
```

As you can see they are really close, but I know I can make it faster.

Comment: OK. This is fun exercise. But you are unlikely to beat `memcpy` in the standard library (not the STL). But if you do you should go talk to the standard library people they would incorporate your code into the compiler. But the standard library version has been optimized constantly over the last 60 years (approx) and utilizes hardware specific optimizations to be optimal for a particular processor.

Comment: Or you read this guys blog and his crazy amount of weird implementations of memcopy: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1110153/apex-memmove-the-fastest-memcpy-memmove-on-x-x-eve